# Unpack one list to another replacing a special symbol in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```py
a = ['first', '___' , 'third', '___' ]
b = ['second', 'fourth']
```

I want to unpack `b` into `a` to replace the special character `___` while keeping the current order.
The result should be

```py
res = ['first', 'second' , 'third', 'fourth']
```

What is the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: So you want to replace each '___' by each element of `b`?

Comment: @DaniMesejo yes

Comment: You could pack and unpack those values if you'd already know their positions, so I would say it's more practical an iteration over those lists. A good example is [the one below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69505349/10301322)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
a = ['first', '___', 'third', '___']
b = ['second', 'fourth']

iter_b = iter(b)
res = [next(iter_b) if ei == '___' else ei for ei in a]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
```